# How do i get my quiz app to show the result section once the last question has been answered?

Tags: javascript, function

Based on my code below, my quiz app goes to the result section before the last question has been answered. Does anyone know what i need to do for my code to go to the result section once the last question has been answered and the user presses next?

```
const onAnswerSelected = (e, selectedIndex) => {
  currentUserAnswer = selectedIndex;
  const isCorrect = currentUserAnswer === currentCorrectAnswer;
  if (isCorrect) {
    console.log("correct")
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("correct");
    gameState.score++;
    console.log(gameState.score)
  } else {
    console.log("wrong")
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("wrong");
  }

  nextBtn.disabled = false;
  setDisabledStateForQuizAnswers(true);

  if (gameState.questionCounter === questions.length) return getResults();  
}
```

and i have tried

```
const onAnswerSelected = (e, selectedIndex) => {
  currentUserAnswer = selectedIndex;
  const isCorrect = currentUserAnswer === currentCorrectAnswer;
  if (isCorrect) {
    console.log("correct")
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("correct");
    gameState.score++;
    console.log(gameState.score)
  } else {
    console.log("wrong")
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("wrong");
  }

  nextBtn.disabled = false;
  setDisabledStateForQuizAnswers(true);

  gameState.questionCounter === maxQuestion && getResults();  
}
```

Comment: Does `gameState.questionCounter` start at 0? If so try `(questions.length-1)`

Comment: Hi @zer00ne, game state starts at 1. However, i’ve also tried (questions.length -1)

Comment: What does that do with the current parameter?:`setDisabledStateForQuizAnswers(true);` Also, if you setting a condition for a number that in/decrements use `<=` or `>=` or `>` or `<`

Comment: if `setDisabledStateForQuizAnswers(true);` is what I think it is then it should go in the `if (){`...`}` block right before `getResults()`

Comment: @zer00ne setDisabledStateForQuizAnswers(true); disables all unselected options. if you meant like this > gameState.questionCounter === setDisabledStateForQuizAnswers(true) && getResults(); i just tried it but did not work.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of `if (gameState.questionCounter >= questions.length) { setDisabledStateForQuizAnswers(true);  results = getResults() }` declare `resluts` anywhere before the `if(){}` like so `let results`

Comment: @zer00ne so something along the lines of                                                                 
 let result = null;
  if (gameState.questionCounter >= questions.length){
    setDisabledStateForQuizAnswers(true) 
    result = getResults(); 
  } ?